# CSOM programming - for regular user

Tags: 2013, client-object-model

Should I as a SP Admin be concerned about when a professional contract developer uses CSOM? I just want to make sure the code is good.

What is your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CSOM is clist-side object model, and user can create the sites/list and manipulate the data as per their permissions. for code review it depend.

As per my experience, We have the Code review in our company for all the server side code deployment but for the client side code deployment we have a process. We have a fear that someone access to sensitive information via script which he should not. So we classified out site collection in 3 ways

- Secret( No Script allowed)
- Confidential( script allowed after Review)
- Proprietor( User can write the script whatever they want from CSOM without review.)

Now its upto your data and control you have.

Comment: I just want to QC the code. for example, getitems without caml is a NO NO. stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

No not really, but as with all custom development: make sure you get it well documented

Answer (score 0):

As Waqas wrotes, scom does everything a user can do. Not in the site that web page resides, but in any site the user can do something!! Please correct me if I'm wrong, but you can't prohibit a site from responding to scom.

Scom is a nice tool to do changes in rendering and offloading the server ( by not writing web parts and refreshing the pages), yet, as an administrator you should always use 
    < script scr= "" > and review the code. 
As for quality control,

Try using jquery- is fast and it gives you a new perspective of programming. Using scom without jquery, you just write a code that could be written in a web part.

$().foreach should always be reviewed, especially when there many items, or ajax involved- at least find some exceptions. In a foreach() & ajax with 650 items, the IE hanged a little, in a foreach & filtering 1.000 options, again a slag.

Log everything but avoid using console.log and use llllog(s) { if (window.console) console.log(s);}. In that way, you can disable the logs and enable them when you need them.

Get the items that you want and the fields that you want ONLY. Sharepoint  server is always faster that User's PC trying to filter them afterwards.

Decide which will be the one and only (or just prime) Explorer! It's a pity to see everything good in Firefox and errors in I.E.

And last, use a low capacity PC for testing - not all the users have i7+16GB RAM

I hope someone will contribute to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have multiple environments created apart from the production? QA, UAT, Release and so on? I would never give access to my production server for testing an app under any circumstance. It is worth creating a small server and let the developer do it there.

Also frequent code reviews where you get to see what actually the developer does will be great, but this does not happen in most of the cases.